# Why does this HTTP request return array lengths rather than content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am working on some stuff here that includes fetching data asynchronously from an API. All is well except when I try pushing the correct answer into the incorrect answers array. All that is being returned are the respective array lengths rather than the content. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Here are the HTML and jQuery codes:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>repl.it</title>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <h3>Answers</h3>
        <ol></ol>
      </div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(() => {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=18",
    async: true,
    success: (data) => {
      let results = data.results;
      $.each(results, (i, difficulty, question) => {
        difficulty = results[i].difficulty;
        question = results[i].question;
        correctAnswer = results[i].correct_answer;
        answers = results[i].incorrect_answers;

        $("ol").append(`
          <li>${answers.push(correctAnswer)}</li>
        `);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Check the [documentation for `$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). Your callback has a wrong number of arguments.

Comment: @Schlaus How so? I've got both the array and the callback function. Everything works fine i.e difficulty, question, answers and correctAnswer all return the appropriate corresponding data. The issue arises when I push the correct answer into the answers array.

Comment: From the docs: callback Type: Function( Integer indexInArray, Object value ). Your callback has three arguments, which are not what you're expecting them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) for the push function.

> Return value
>
> The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.

Aat the end of your function you are pushing the correctAnswer to answers which returns the length of answers array and you are showing that in your html. That's perfectly natural.

Push first and then create the html tag.

Check this;

```js
$(() => {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=18",
    async: true,
    success: (data) => {
      let results = data.results;
      $.each(results, (i, difficulty, question) => {
        difficulty = results[i].difficulty;
        question = results[i].question;
        correctAnswer = results[i].correct_answer;
        answers = results[i].incorrect_answers;

        answers.push(correctAnswer)
        $("ol").append(`
          <li>${correctAnswer}</li>
        `);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h3>Answers</h3>
    <ol></ol>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @CollinsOrlando Are you sure? click on "Run code snippet" on my answer. It shows some values. Not sure if those are the ones you want

Comment: Those are the correct answers/choice being returned. What I was looking for was all the answers (choices). Nevertheless, I found a solution.

Comment: Actually yours was the correct answer. You just had 'correctAnswer' rather than 'answers' in the appended HTML. 

Any idea why pushing it directly into the (incorrect) answers array i.e. answers = results[i].incorrect_answers.push(correctAnswer) doesn't work? Thanks!